# Why does connecting flight need a security check at connection airport?

Tags: air-travel, transit, airport-security

I'm just wondering why when flying with connection flights, when I come at the connecting airport, straight from the arrivals and to the departures, why do I have go through a security check.

Since I'm coming straight from the plane and I'm not leaving the air side, why is this extra, annoying, check for?

I've tried to search but all I've found is [something on LHR website that doesn't explain much](http://www.heathrowairport.com/heathrow-airport-guide/flight-connections/faqs).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are locations that fly to LHR that do not conform to international norms regarding international safety. Lagos, Nigeria, for example, does not conform to certain protocols, and Therefore is not considered secure. Rather than ferreting out individual flights, it is considered prudent simply to screen all passengers again.

Comment: I didn't asked about LHR in particular, but i assume the answer is true for other major airport as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It boils down to airport organisation. There are airports where you can simply walk to your connecting flight, but in cases where it is difficult to distinguish OD passengers from transfering passengers everybody is checked.

Comment: In all airports i'v traveled through so far, you must pass a security check as soon as you head to the "transfer" area, so if you know about airports where this isn't so, i would like to hear about

Comment: @ISAE Often it is small regional airports which do not have a separate airside arrival and departure area, though at O'Hare there are walkways between terminals which allow you to remain in the secure area.

Comment: @ISAE lisbon for example

Comment: @ISAE Quite a few big airports too, Singapore Changi and Kuala Lumpur Int'l come to mind.  See: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34818/why-is-security-screening-done-at-the-gate-at-ams-schiphol-airport-amsterdam

Comment: At least in the United States, with only domestic flights, almost all large airports allow you to transfer from one flight to the next without leaving the secured area or being re-screened. The only exceptions I've seen is where you need to change terminals and the terminals are not directly interconnected.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. I haven't flew those destinations yet:)

Comment: Prague airport allows direct transfer within the same terminal.