# What is the baggage drop deadline for Eva Air at Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport (TPE) for international flights?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, check-in, taiwan, tpe

What is the baggage drop deadline at the check-in counter for Eva Air at Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport (TPE) for international flights (to SFO if that matters)?

[Evaair.com - managing your trip](https://www.evaair.com/en-global/managing-your-trip/airport-and-transportation/airports-in-taiwan/taiwan-taoyuan-international-airport/) says:

> Counters are opened gradually from 04:15, please check your check-in island at the airport.  All flights are closed punctually 60 minutes before flight departure.

However I don't know whether this 60-minute deadline also apply to the baggage drop or the baggage drop deadline is before 60 minutes.

On the same page as the URL listed above, I see that the "In-Town Check-in" does have a difference between the non-baggage check-in deadline (2 hours before flight departure) and the  baggage check-in deadline (3 hours before flight departure):

> Check-in for all EVA/UNI flights departed from Taoyuan International Airport and closed punctually 2 hours before flight departure that day. Baggage check-in will be closed 3 hours before flight departure. Flights departed to Canada are not acceptable in A1 station.

but I don't know about the check-in at the airport.

The confirmation email I received when purchasing the flight ticket doesn't contain the information.

Comment: Have you asked the airline?

Comment: @David I don't have much phone credit and whatever they tell me by phone tend to be less of an evidence than something written somewhere.

Comment: Sure, but if no one responds — and no one has, yet -- asking might generate useful info. EVA Air's contact page is here: https://www.evaair.com/en-us/contact-us-and-help/contact-us/

Comment: @MarkMayoSupportsMonica I called the Eva Air customer service: my interlocutor apparently couldn't understand me. I called a second time but they wouldn't pick up the phone. And at the airport I forgot to ask the question when dropping my baggages. it's really annoying that many airlines do not clearly and spontaneously specify deadlines, but I think it is in their habits not to respect their passengers' time ("come three hours early and wait at the airport!")

Comment: Usually when there are no further details, the airport check-in and baggage drop deadlines are the same.

Comment: @DialFrost thanks! Airlines are amazingly good at not giving clearly all deadlines. https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/50238/1810

Answer (score 1):

Seems it should be 2-3 hours before flight:

> From [Taoyuan Airport - Departure Procedures](https://www.taoyuan-airport.com/outbound?lang=en):
>
> > Please go the check-in counter of your airline two to three hours before your flight departure time to complete check-in procedures.

> From [Star Flyer - Airport Check-In Counter (Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport)](https://www.starflyer.jp/int_en/checkin/taoyuan/counter01.html):
>
> > Be sure to complete check-in at least 40 minutes prior to departure time.

However airports are very good at not giving clear deadlines to things apart from flight departure etc. Of course.

Comment: Yes sorry, jcaron is likely right but would be nice to have some confirmation from the airline.

Comment: I called the Eva Air customer service: my interlocutor apparently couldn't understand me. I called a second time but they wouldn't pick up the phone. And at the airport a few years ago when I was there, I forgot to ask the question when dropping my baggage.