# What is the minimum time to check-in at the counter for an international flight with United Airlines where the first leg is domestic?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, check-in, united-airlines, timetables

What is the minimum time to check-in for an international flight with United Airlines where the first leg is domestic?

I read on https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/United_Airlines/checkin.php ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191210223603/http://web.archive.org/screenshot/https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/United_Airlines/checkin.php)):

> The minimum time to check-in for a United Airlines (UA) flight is:
>
> - 30 minutes before scheduled departure time for US domestic flights
> - 60 minutes before scheduled departure time for international flights to/from the US

I'm not sure  whether the deadline to check-in at the counter  is 30 minutes or 60 minutes since the first since the first leg of my flight is domestic.

Also, this contradicts the information given at https://www.flysanjose.com/airlines/united ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191210224052/https://www.flysanjose.com/airlines/united)):

> Minimum Check-In Time: 30 minutes before scheduled departure

My flight is SFO, US --([UA 540](https://www.google.com/search?q=UA+540))--> IAH, US --([UA 854](https://www.google.com/search?q=ua+854))--> LIM, Peru. Flights UA 540 and UA 854 are taken on the same day, and were booked at the same time via the United Airlines website.

Comment: 30 minutes before departure of your first segment is more than 60 minutes prior to your second segment, unless you're boarding a time machine.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Or if the first leg is a [53-second flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Westray_to_Papa_Westray_flight&oldid=923811748)  :-) But I'd prefer the time machine.

Answer (score 3):

The International check-in cut-off of 60 minutes applies ONLY before the departure time of the international flight in your itinerary.

If your itinerary consists of a domestic flight followed by an international flight, then the domestic check-in cut-off applies to the domestic flight.

The 60 minute cut-off for international flights primarily exists due to US Government requirements that required the airline to provide the Government with information on all passengers on the flight no later than 60 minutes before departure - thus the airlines require you to be checked in by that time.

Note that although 30 minutes is the check-in cut-off time for a domestic flight, many airlines/airports will have an earlier baggage drop-off time if you are checking bags. United lists their times [on their website](https://www.united.com/ual/en/us/fly/travel/airport/process.html), but in most cases check-in with bags is required at least 45 minutes before departure.

Comment: Mirrors for a page like that are dangerous as they potentially provide out-of-date information

Answer (score 0):

A 30 minute check in cutoff only means that the counter will be open, NOT that you are actually guaranteed to make the flight. In either case you need to be at the gate 15 minutes before departure. If you need more than 15 minutes to get through security and to get to the gate you'll be out of luck regardless of check in time.

30 minute also will not allow you to check luggage.

Whether the 30-minute or the 60-minute cut off applies depends on where exactly the document check happens and what specific doc check is required. If you really want to be sure, you should call United or your specific flight.

It's typically much easier and safer to check in online. If you have no checked luggage, you can skip the check in counter alltogther

Comment: "Whether the 30-minute or the 60-minute cut off applies depends on where exactly the document check happens and what specific doc check is required. " -> As specified in the question, the check-in happens at the United Airlines counter at SFO. Typically check-in deadlines are mentioned somewhere online, because airlines don't want each customer to call them to ask about it.

Comment: "It's typically much easier and safer to check in online. " -> I tried and it's not possible in my case: the United Airlines website is asking me to check in at the counter.

Comment: "30 minute also will not allow you to check luggage." -> Is that true for only international flights, or domestic flights as well?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I was once denied checking into a US domestic flight because I attempted to check in with luggage 50 minutes before the flight.  I was told the minimum was 60 minutes with luggage so that the luggage has time to transit through the system.  And this was at a small airport.

Comment: @PeterM was it United Airlines? Definitely bag drop can have its own deadline, e.g. [What is the baggage drop deadline for Eva Air at Taiwan Taoyuan International Airport (TPE) for international flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/147756/1810)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I can't remember what airline, but I just realized that my itinerary was like yours: Domestic Leg then International Leg.  Because I was refused checkin I had to rebook via another city and experienced a boat load of weather related delays.