# How to contact EVA airways?

Tags: bookings, airlines

I have a booking with EVA Airways that I would like to modify.  The modification I would like to make is not possible to do online (they even have on their website a [long list of modifications which require calling them](https://booking.evaair.com/flyeva/EVA/B2C/modifyflight.aspx#bookmark1)).

The problem is: **I cannot find a working phone number for EVA Airways!**

+1-800-695-1188 is the phone number listed on my ticket, but it just plays a recording and disconnects.

I've tried the phone numbers for the [New York and Los Angeles](https://www.evaair.com/en-us/customer-services/contact-us/contact/) offices, but they also just say "all lines are currently busy" and disconnect.

I messaged them on Twitter, but got no response.

I messaged them on Facebook, and they said I should use their website or app.

I emailed info@evaair.com but did not get any response.

EVA Airways is a very highly rated airline, so I would have expected they would at least have a working phone number.  I can't even get on hold.  My last resort is to call their main office in Taipei (haven't tried yet because of time zone difference).  Does anyone here know another way to get EVA Airways on the phone?

**ANSWER:** Calling their central office in Taipei at +886-2-2501-1999 worked.  Less than 10 minutes wait, and they had service in English.

Comment: @DimitriVulis What is this 1-805-410-9066 number? Searching for it on google returns some sketchy looking websites claiming it can connect me to the customer service of any(?!) airline. Not sure I should trust them with my reservation info and credit card info if I don't know who they are.

Comment: "EVA Airways is a very highly rated airline" where did you see that? Pretty bad in my experience

Comment: They are rated 5 stars by Skytrax (same as Singapore Air, better than Emirates) and they are #8 in airlineratings.com 2022 top 20 airlines.

Comment: Thanks, Skytrax don't even take into account the phone customer service so they are incompetent (see https://skytraxratings.com/airlines/eva-air-rating for their rating criteria). You can see on https://www.airlineratings.com/passenger-reviews/eva-air/ that Eva gets crap review from actual customers, and I'll add mine soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2019 I [had](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/147756/1810) to call Eva Airways and I used +886 2 2501 1999. They don't always pick up the phone, you may have to wait over two hours and you may have to speak Chinese. At least, that was my experience with them. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be the correct answer.  Though luckily I was on hold for only 10 minutes and they did have service in English.